JQuery script with AJAX to validate form input
I am trying to write a script to validate the data when a user clicks the submit button on a form. Essentially, I want to check if the new input is already in the database.

If it is, it must tell the user and then exit out of the function.
If it is not, it must then check and see if the user has not submitted a blank field. If the user has inputted a blank field, it must also exit out of the function.

I can get the two scripts to work independently of each other, but when I try and merge the scripts to create one, it goes on to submit the entry if it was found or if it was blank and writes the data. My troubleshooting alert tell me all that I need to know, but it just seems to not execute the return false; and exit out.
Any thoughts or help will be appreciated.
function ValidateMyForm() {
var MFormFieldCategoryName = document.forms["MyForm"]["FormFieldCategoryName"].value;
$.post("category_lookup_existing.cfm", {
        MFormFieldCategoryName: MFormFieldCategoryName
    },
    function(data) {
        // Callback Function Alert on number of records in DB Table
        alert("Existing Records = " + data);
        if (data > 0) {
            alert('Found existing entry')
            $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').val("");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('Entry Not Found')
            if (MFormFieldCategoryName == "") {
                alert("Please Input a Category Name.");
                $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').focus();
                $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').css({
                    "background-color": "#fff2e6"
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').css({
                    "background-color": "#fff"
                });
                var CheckProductName = "OK";
            }
            if (CheckProductName == "OK") {
                //$("#loading").show();
                //$("#LocationMain").hide();
                ShowSavingv2('L')
            }
        }
    });

}

$("#MyForm").on("submit", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); const MFormFieldCategoryName = this.FormFieldCategoryName.value; ... You need to not submit the form when you do this. Your false is not returning from the outer function

"it goes on to submit the entry": please show the code that connects this validation function to the form submission. It would probably help to show the examples of how it worked independently.

I have added the additional code, button, form. Thank you for looking.

@mplungjan: thanks for the pointer, I think I get your suggestion and agree that the false is not returning. I will see if I can model the new script on your suggestion.

Remember to remove onclick="return ValidateMyForm()">  when you change the code to use the submit event

@mplungjan: Thanks for the steer in the right direction - massively appreciate it. I have it working now, but slightly differently. Removed the onclick (thanks for the reminder) and I have attached the working script. Not sure if it is messy or not and, in terms of other hard core developers, acceptable, but it works.

How do I mark your suggestion as accepted @mplungjan?

It's ok. The question is now quite messy. Perhaps too messy for others to find useful. You could just delete it

Answers do not belong in questions. Either add an answer and remove it from the question, or, as @mplungjan suggests, delete the question as it is unlikely to help others.

Thank you @HereticMonkey.

THE FINAL WORKING SCRIPT
This is what I ended up with. Checks to see if the record is already on the database, if so, it does not go forward. If the user submits a blank entry, it highlights it and takes one back to the input field. If all good, not empty and not exists, then it submits the form.
Thanks for your help mplungjan
    $(function() {
    $("#CheckDBEntry").click(function() {
        var empID = document.forms["MyForm"]["FormFieldCategoryName"].value;
        $.post("category_lookup_existing.cfm", {
                EmpID: empID
            },
            function(data) {
                // This is my callack function
                //alert("Return data " + data);
                //$( "#content" ).html( data );
                //Check if data > 0 meaning existing entry
                if (data > 0) {
                    alert('Unable to Save Record (Existing)')
                    $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').val("");
                    $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').focus();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var MFormFieldCategoryName = document.forms["MyForm"]["FormFieldCategoryName"].value;
                    // MFormFieldCategoryName
                    // MFormFieldCategoryName
                    // MFormFieldCategoryName
                    // MFormFieldCategoryName
                    // MFormFieldCategoryName
                    if (MFormFieldCategoryName == "") {
                        alert("Please Input a Valid Category Name.");
                        $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').focus();
                        $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').css({
                            "background-color": "#fff2e6"
                        });
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $('#FormFieldCategoryNameID').css({
                            "background-color": "#fff"
                        });
                        var CheckCatName = "OK";
                    }
                    if (
                        CheckCatName == "OK"
                    ) {
                        //$("#loading").show();
                        //$("#LocationMain").hide();
                        ShowSavingv2('L')
                        $('form#myForm').submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        // to prevent the default action
        /* alert('here')*/
        return false;
    });
});

